# Как переопределить классы стилей messages django

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, django, bootstrap5

Как можно переопределить стили для системы оповещения (messages) в Django, чтобы они совпадали с классами стилей bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужно переопределить MESSAGE_TAGS в settings.py проекта и дописать нужные стили (bootstrap5)

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages    
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-primary',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}
```